# keyup event not caught with Angular 2 @HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a google maps that should capture keyup events. My component is a parent of the google maps div. It works fine with Chrome, it does not with Firefox or IE (not tested wtith Edge).

My component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['dashboard.component.css'],
  host: {
    '[attr.tabindex]': '-1'
  },
  providers: []
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

  /* some functions and other stuff here 
  * ...
  */

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) keyup(e) {
    console.log('This will be called with Chrome, not with the others.');
  }
};
```

Have you experienced the same ? (Tell me if you need more info).
Thanks

[edit]
I've tried catching the `keyup` events by using ElementRef and setting my event handler to the `onkeyup` property of the `elementRef.nativeElement`, with no luck

Answer (score 7):

Try listening to the `window:keyup` or `document:keyup` event instead of simply `keyup`.

[Source](https://coryrylan.com/blog/listening-to-angular-key-events-with-host-listeners)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the `window:keyup` event fails to work with `@HostListener`, though it works in other cases in the same application. Try to use the `document:keyup` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Chrome propogates the keyup event to the parent while other browsers dont. You can try subscribing to the map's event directly.

```
@ViewChild('myMap')
map: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {};

ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.map.nativeElement, 'keyup', (event) => {
        // ...
    });
}
```

and in the template:

```
<div #myMap>...</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. I added `tabindex="-1"`. It still works with Chrome.